# Python: What is wrong with the indexing logic in my code?

Tags: python, indexing

"You are given an array of n integers and an integer k. Find and print the number of `(i,j)` pairs where `i<j and a[i] + a[j]` is evenly divisible by k."

Sample input would be:

```
6 3
1 3 2 6 1 2
```

where 6 is n, 3 is k and the second line is the array of integers. The output for this input would be 5.

Here is my code, but i am not passing the test cases and am almost positive it has to do with how i am indexing it.

```
import sys


n,k = input().strip().split(' ')
n,k = [int(n),int(k)]
a = [int(a_temp) for a_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]

count=0;

for i in range(n):
    curr = n-i
    for j in range(curr):
        if i < i + j:
            if k % (a[i] + a[i+j]) ==0:
                count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Also, followup question: Is this method i am approaching an efficient way of going about it?

Comment: you are using `i+j` in your code as the `j` in the question, right? If yes, you are solving it not for `i<i+j` but for `i<=i+j`.You also you need to move the `k` to the right hand side when checking for divisibility

Comment: I'm not sure if `for j in range(curr):` is good. I would do rather `for j in range(i+1, n):` This `i < i + j:` you can write as `0 < j`. This is wrong `k % (a[i] + a[i+j]) == 0` - you need  `(a[i] + a[i+j]) % k == 0`. Besides I would use `for i in range(n-1):` (without last element - you don't have to compare last element with last element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this ...

```
import sys 
n,k = input().strip().split(' ') 
n,k = [int(n),int(k)] 
a = [int(a_temp) for a_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]        
print(sum([1 for i in range(n) for j in range(i) if (a[i]+a[j])%k==0]))
```

Comment: You can remove [] in the sum and use it like a generator as in `sum(1 for i in range(n) for j in range(i) if (a[i]+a[j])%k==0)`

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in the print statement? What does it mean "1 for i" and why "for j in range (i)"?

Comment: '1 for i' is use when if condition is true then it append 1 in list and at the end we take the sum of list which gives the count of pairs.
'for j in range i' is use to check all pairs with i< j condition

Comment: Also, how is that line of code checking to see if i < j ?

Comment: For more about list comprehensions please visit http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html

Answer (score 2):

- `k % ...` means "`k` is divisible by ...", not "... is divisible by `k`".
- `if i < i + j` is not very useful; you're better off doing what furas recommends in comments.

Comment: Wow, duh! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code also accepts the cases where `i==j` You need to fix your loop too

Comment: Yea, i did in my submitted code. What is wrong with the loop? Do you just mean the i==j case?

Comment: I wrote something else when @furas didn't comment yet. If he makes his comment into an answer, you should totally choose him (or Aman) over me.

Comment: Okay i will. Very noble of you Amadan

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to make use of `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

count = 0
for i, j in combinations(range(n), 2):
    if i < j and (a[i] + a[j]) % k == 0:
        print i, j
        count += 1
```

## Discussion

1. `range(n)` returns a list of indices 0 .. n-1
2. `combinations(range(n), 2)` will yield a list of two indices (without duplications)
3. `(a[i] + a[j]) % k == 0` is the test that your asked
4. Note that `combinations` will yield pairs of i, j where i is always less than j, but the test `i < j` is there as a paranoid measure